# Creating a JavaFX node with title? or a stage within a stage

Tags: user-interface, javafx

[how would i go about creating a node with a title on it like this screenshot?
at least i think that it is a node or is it a stage within a stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyLb2.png)

Comment: You can't put a stage within a stage. Just create the individual components and lay them out in an appropriate manner.

Answer (score 1):

that is called titlepane, you can give the pane a title in the header.
The titlepane is an groupnode in the javafx scenegraph.

A Stage can not be in the stage by himself, because the stage is a window from the used operating system, and in the window will the nodes rendered by the scenegraph used low level graphics api.

Graphics API:
JavaFX uses:

Windows: DirectX;

Linux: OpenGL;

Mac: Cocoa (OpenGL)